# Unable to log in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpMyAdmin on my local(running Apache & windows). My problem is, I kept getting this error:

## 2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I have checked the error file, and it shows:

```
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain 
name, using xxxxx for ServerName
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest 
authentication ...
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 8680: Child process is running
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 8680: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 8680: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 8680: Starting thread to listen on 
port 10081.
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 8680: Starting thread to listen on 
port 80.
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:48 2017] [notice] Child 1096: All worker threads have 
exited.
[Wed Dec 20 10:33:49 2017] [notice] Child 1096: Child process is exiting"
```

What does it means and how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Before you start apache and MySQL check your port status. Paste the result here

Comment: working in windows?Linux?

Comment: edited the desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your my.cnf file, and start the socket mode, as similar as

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql.sock';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
```

and try to access it

Comment: Please check your apache error log, what error happened?

Comment: it says that starting 64 workers, acquired the start mutex,starting listen on port 10081 and 80

Comment: it is not the error description, can you attach your phpmyadmin's  config.inc.php? and by the way, where you deploy the file?